# Download FreeBSD print system

Tags: freebsd, printing, print-server

Where can I get to download FreeBSD print system?

I have webmin installed on mac os x 10.6.4 and when i want to setup printer administration i get this error

```
The spool directory /var/spool/lpd does not exist on your system, which indicates that the FreeBSD print system is not installed.
```

Answer (score 3):

[CUPS on FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/cups/)

Answer (score 3):

Cups is not LPD!
Take a look at the [FreeBSD LPD Documentation](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/corp-net-guide/printserving-lpr-freebsd.html)

Answer (score 1):

[CUPS](http://www.cups.org/) is probably what you want. Install it as a package or from ports.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.freebsddiary.org/cups.php check this link :D